# Accessing a Plugin from a Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

How would I go about accessing the Bundle-Fu plugin from this rake task?

I have tried everything out and nothing seems to work.

> Note: `assets_javascript` & `assets_css` are both arrays of files that are pulled from a central location to keep this rake task and the view DRY.

```
desc "Generate cached css/js files" 
task :asset_cache_generate => :environment do
    puts 'Caching Javascript & CSS Files'
    bundle do
        javascript_include_tag assets_javascript
        stylesheet_link_tag assets_css
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

`- Tom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `bundle` is mixed into ActionView so you can only call it from a templace instance.

Unfortunately, you can't neither mix it into a custom class nor use it in a Rake task because it depends on many Rails template helpers/resources (concat, flash...). It would be too hard to reproduce all of them in order to make the method working.

See http://github.com/timcharper/bundle-fu/blob/8056fd05c7ee4f637eb6137d544e91065400daab/lib/bundle_fu.rb